# Estimating the difference between an irrational and a rational number

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The following is a basic analysis question which I find quite difficult.

> Let $\alpha$ be any irrational number. Show that for any positive
> integer $n$, there exists a ${\bf positive}$ integer $q_n$ and a
> integer $p_n$ such that
>
> $$ \left| \alpha - \dfrac{p_n }{q_n} \right| < \dfrac{1}{nq_n} $$
>
> And, moreover, show that $\{ p_n \}$  and $\{ q_n \}$ can be chosen in
> such that we have
>
> $$ \left| \alpha - \dfrac{p_n }{q_n} \right| < \dfrac{1}{q_n^2} $$

### Thought:

What I tried to do is to remove the absolute value to have $- 1/nq_n < \alpha - p_n/q_n < 1/nq_n $ and then

$$ \dfrac{n p_n - 1 }{n q_n } < \alpha < \dfrac{ np_n + 1 }{nq_n} $$

This approach leads nowhere.

So, I thought maybe this may help: So, we start with $\alpha $ and we there is a positive integer $q_1$ such that $q_1 \alpha > 1 $ by archimedean property. I am having difficulties here trying to construct $q_n$ and $p_n$. Is this the right strategy?

Comment: For the first part, multiplying both sides of the inequality by $q_n$ makes it a lot easier to understand. Hint: pigeonhole principle is quite useful.

Comment: For the first part see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351545/non-differentiability-in-mathbb-r-setminus-mathbb-q-of-the-modification-of-th/351578#351578).