# non differentiable, integrable function

Tags: calculus, analysis

Can a function be unable to be differentiated, but is integrable?

By unable to be differentiated, I mean at any arbitrary x coordinate. Thank you

Comment: Thomae's function is integrable over $[0,1]$, but [differentiable nowhere](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197788/proving-thomaes-function-is-nowhere-differentiable).

Comment: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m321/nondiffble.pdf

Answer (score 4):

See the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).