# Show that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> A function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by
>   $$
>     f(x)= 
> \begin{cases}
>     0,& \text{if } ~x=0 ~~\text{or}~~ x ~\text{is irrational} \\
>     \frac{1}{q^3}, &   \text{if}~~ x=\frac{p}{q} ~~ \text{where}~~ p\in \mathbb{Z}, q\in \mathbb{N}~~ \text{and} \gcd(p,q)=1.         
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> Show that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=0$.

A hints to the problem is given as 
$0\le |\frac{f(x)}{x}|\le x^2$ for $x \ne 0.$ I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help.

Comment: I suppose you mean irrational, not irrotational?

Comment: irrational, I have changed

Comment: A useful related [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197788/proving-thomaes-function-is-nowhere-differentiable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $h \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$,

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac 0h=0.$

When $0 \neq h=\frac pq \in \Bbb Q$,

Consider $0 \le |\frac {f(h)}{h}| =|\frac { \frac 1{q^3}}{\frac pq}|=|\frac {1}{q^2 p}| \le |\frac {p^3}{q^2 p}|=|(\frac pq)^2|=h^2$.

What we have got is $0 \le |\frac {f(h)}{h}| \le h^2......(*)$

Hence using sandwich theorem in $(*)$, $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(h)}{h}=0.$

Since both of the above limits exist and are equal, $f$ is differentiable. Also $f'(0)=0$ as it can be seen.

Comment: Please elaborate how you get $|\frac {1}{q^2 p}| \le |\frac {p^3}{q^2 p}|$

Comment: @user1942348 $\because 1 \le |p^3|$.